# If $\alpha$ is the angle between two curves, find $\cos (\alpha)$ in terms of parametric representation of the curves.

Tags: real-analysis

If $\alpha$ is the angle between two curves, find $\cos (\alpha)$ in terms of parametric representation of the curves.  Answer in book:

[image]

Is this answer correct?  I keep getting a minus sign between the top terms.

Outline of my approach:
We draw a horizontal at the point of intersection.  By simple geometry the angle between the tangents is $\alpha=\theta + \phi$ where $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the angles between the $x$ axis and the tangent to the curves.  Taking cosine both sides, and using the fact that

$\cos (t)=\pm \frac{\dot{x}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2}}$ and 
$\sin (t)=\pm \frac{\dot{y}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2}}$ as given in book for angle $t$ between $x$ axis and tangent to curve.  I find that I always get the negative after using the additional formula for $\cos$ after expansion.

Comment: If you get a different result then it would be constructive to tell *how* you computed it.

Comment: @MartinR Ok I put in my method.  Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that
$$\gamma:\quad u\mapsto{\bf z}(u)=\bigl(x(u),y(u)\bigr)$$
is the parametric representation of a curve  $\gamma\subset{\mathbb R}^2$. Then for any parameter value the vector ${\bf z}'(u)=\bigl(x'(u),y'(u)\bigr)$, if $\ne{\bf 0}$, is a tangent vector to $\gamma$ at the point ${\bf z}(u)$. In the problem at hand two curves $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$ are given, and it is assumed that for two particular parameter values $u$, resp. $v$, the curves intersect at a common point ${\bf z}_1(u)={\bf z}_2(v)$. In order to find the angle of intersection we have to make use of the following fact:

Given two nonzero vectors ${\bf a}$, ${\bf b}\in{\mathbb R}^n$ the cosine of the enclosed angle $\alpha$ is given by
$$\cos\alpha={{\bf a}\cdot{\bf b}\over|{\bf a}|\>|{\bf b}|}\ ,$$
whereby the dot denotes the scalar product. The latter is computed as follows:
$${\bf a}\cdot{\bf b}=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\,b_i\ .$$
Now apply this to the two vectors ${\bf z}_1'(u)$, $\>{\bf z}_2'(v)$.

Comment: The book that the question is from doesn't feature linear algebra.  In any case how does one get the derivative into the picture?  Do you just derive each vector component with respect to its parameter?